# convert php code to array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, explode

I use codeigniter, i send tow input as array to following php code, but following php code don't get it as array, how change php code for get value array?

```
<input type="text" name="date[]">
<input type="text" name="date[]">
```

```
$date = $this -> input -> post('date');

$jdate = jgmdate("Y/m/j");
list($year_now, $month_now, $day_now) = explode('/', $jdate, 3);
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', $date, 3);//Line Number: 97
if($year>=$year_now && $month<=12 ) {
$j2g = $this->convert_date->JalaliToGregorian($year, $month, $day);
return $j2g[0]."/".$j2g[1]."/".$j2g[2];
}else {
  return '0';
}
```

with above code i have this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: admin/model.php
>
> Line Number: 97

-

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 2
>
> Filename: admin/model.php
>
> Line Number: 97

-

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined offset: 1
>
> Filename: admin/model.php
>
> Line Number: 97

Answer (score 1):

You need to read and understand the error messages:

```
Message: Array to string conversion (Line 97)
```

Meaning you're converting an array to a string. That normally results in the following string : `"Array"`:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', "Array", 3);//Line Number: 97
```

Using that `explode` on a the `"Array"` string returns the following:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Array"
}
```

So an array with one string containing `"Array"` on index `0`. So:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = array('Array');
```

Results in:

```
$year = "Array"; $month = NULL; $day = NULL;
```

Obviously this is not what you wanted. I don't know what you wanted, maybe this?:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = $date;
```

But maybe not, because you wrote you have two date fields, not three. See as well [Marc B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392810/convert-php-code-to-array/7392905#7392905).

Comment: i changed this `list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', "Array", 3);//Line Number: 97` to `$date_array = array(1) {
                [0]=>
                string(5) "$date_go"
              }
            list($year, $month, $day) = array($date_array);` it don't work and this `$date_array = array(1) {` line have error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected**. did i done true?

Comment: That will never work. You need an array with three elements (0,1,2) to have the [`list`](http://php.net/list) work. Please add example data for your date fields you outlined at the beginning of your question.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean,
Please make changes in my code

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't understand what you mean. Please make changes to *your* question. Please specify what you're specifically looking for, what is your concrete input data, which values are entered into the form fields?

Answer (score 0):

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', $date, 3);//Line Number: 97
```

At the point this line runs, $date is an array, not a string. You can't explode an array. If I'm understanding your code correctly, you'd probably want to do:

```
foreach ($date as $d) {
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('/', $d, 3);
}
```

and process each of the "dates" submitted from the form separately.

Comment: this change have tow error: `Message: Undefined offset: 1`, `Message: Undefined offset: 2`. !?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, $date is already an array.

so, you need 3 input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="date[]">
<input type="text" name="date[]">
<input type="text" name="date[]">
```

then **$date** should be an array already. check `var_dump($this->input->post('date'));`

```
$date = $this -> input -> post('date');

$jdate = jgmdate("Y/m/j");
list($year_now, $month_now, $day_now) = explode('/', $jdate, 3);

$year = $date[0];
$month = $date[1];
$day = $date[2];

if($year>=$year_now && $month<=12 ) {
$j2g = $this->convert_date->JalaliToGregorian($year, $month, $day);
return $j2g[0]."/".$j2g[1]."/".$j2g[2];
}else {
  return '0';
}
```